# Where is the transpose (fine tune) button in Live 11?

Tags: ableton-live, transposition

I would like to change the the pitch in cts not just st (semitones). This question sounds a bit stupid. The button used to be there, because I have successfully used it.

Below there is a screenshot of an audio file in clipview. The Transpose button that is supposed to be there (as shown in the manual) is not there.

[image: Clipview screenshot]

Comment: Did you previously successfully use the button in Live 11 or only in previous versions?

Comment: In the same version, Live 11. The button disappeared somehow.

Comment: I have 11 suite.

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  did the knob just disappear?

Comment: Well it did, but I now the answer of how to get around this now. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think you need to click the right zero instead of the left and type in the cts instead of using the knob. Pretty sure that works, but let me know if there I can also use the knob. This is a very tedious way of doing.